# Cubical delusion : Cubes one coloured red and other green except on 1 face are cut into 27 & 64 cubes. How many are red only on 1 face?

Tags: geometry

There are **two cubes** of different sizes. One of these is **coloured red on all the faces**, while other is **coloured green on all the faces except one** which is coloured **red**. The one which is red on all faces is cut into **27 equal cubes**, while the other one is cut into **64 equal cubes** which are mixed up with other cubes.

> How many cubes are coloured red only on one face?
>   (a) 10
>                          (b) 16
>   (c) 20   
>                        (d) 22

---

The answer is given as **(b)** i.e. **16.**

*But, when I tried I got it as

cube I : 
6 cubes with only one red face

cube II: 
4 cubes with only one red face

         8 cubes with one red and one green face

         4 cubes with one red faceand two green faces*

**So, it should be either 22** *(if I take it as "How many cubes are coloured red, **only on one face**?")* **or 10** *(if I take it as "How many cubes are coloured **red only**, on one face?")*

**So can you tell me whether the answer in the book is correct, or the answer I got (which one? first or second?) is correct?**

*Help me !! I am having exam tomorrow!*

Comment: I think that from your interpretations, your answers are right. I would say 22. I don't get why the problem says: "which are mixed up with other cubes." ¿Why is that relevant?

Comment: Agree, the answer is 22 to me too. I still don't get what is meant by `which are mixed up with other cubes` though

Comment: I also am confused. Please ignore it

Comment: I think Ross Millikan is correct

Comment: I guess the "which are mixed..." is just to mix up matters ;-)

Answer (score 4):

I agree with your logic and can read the question either way to get 10 or 22.  I think the mixed up with the other cubes is just supposed to tell you to count small cubes from both big cubes, which you are doing.

Comment: So the answer is 10 or 22?

Comment: @chndn:  I don't think the question is clearly written.  Your logic resulting in each of 10 and 22 is correct.  I think I would go with 22, but without conviction.